# Check if an element has changed its position

Tags: javascript

So, this is my code:

```
<div onmousedown="draggable(this);"></div>
```

What is the best method to detect when the user has clicked on the div if it has changed its position?

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code in the question so we can help.

Comment: I have not a code, I'm thinking on how to implement this features with the code that does not interfere with the function draggable() that I will create later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done with variables to track the last position of the div.

```
var x = divVar.pageX
  , y = divVar.pageY;

//then during your mouseup
function checkPositionOnMouseup(div){
  if(div.pageX !== x || div.pageY !== y){
    console.log("MOVED!");
    x = div.pageX;    //update variables to new position
    y = div.pageY;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[dragStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#dragstart) event will fire when user begins to drag the element.

Comment: This part I do not care, I'm interested in the next part, ie to detect in onmouseup event if the item has been moved.

Comment: Alright then `drop` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#drop

Comment: But I need to use onmousedown event to move the element!